# How to start Middleman? cannot load such file -- less (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, middleman

I am learning Middleman. I installed Vagrant and have set up everything about that. But I have a problem at the end, when I call "bundle exec middleman", the Middleman should start after that regularly. But I get this message:

```
"var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:144:in 'require':cannot load such file -- less (LoadError)"
```

What should I do? I am working on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you forgot to add [`less`](https://rubygems.org/gems/less) to your `Gemfile`:

```
 gem 'less'
```

Comment: Forgot?  Where was that ever mentioned!

Comment: @meesern Not sure what you're asking here about a four year old question.

Comment: The issue is not four years old, it's affecting me in 2020.

Answer (score 1):

As @tadman has pointed out adding

```
gem 'less'
```

is (possibly) a solution, but here is a little more detail on why you might have this problem migrating or developing a site:

If you initialise a middleman project with `middleman init`, then start working on your site with 'middleman serve' everything should be fine.  But if, at some point you add a file with a `.less` extension you will get this error when you next restart middleman.  Note that you might not knowingly have added `less` files - fontawsome for example can add .less versions of the css deep in it's directory structure.

I say that installing less is only possibly a solution since the 'less' gem was broken when I tried it (it was not able to install due to an old dependency on `therubyracer`

Deleting `.less` files that you didn't want or know you had is also a solution.